# Create a Mac Application Installer and Passing Arguments on Launch

Tags: macos, installation, argument-passing, launch

Couple questions on creating a mac installer.

1) Should any frameworks from /Developer/SDKs/ be included/packaged into the application file?

2) When we normally launch the executable we pass it an argument to point it at our servers, is there a way to encode this information into the Unix Executable File found in Contents/MacOS/?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

1) No.

2) Yes. http://developer.apple.com/Mac/library/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/LaunchServicesKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001431-106825

Comment: Based on the link you sent, that would create a environmental variable. What I am trying to achieve is similar to when you edit an executable in xcode, and you can specify "Arguments to be passed on launch" I want to be able to pass those arguments into the application when I run it from the Finder. Very similar to how in windows you create a shortcut that points to an exe file and give it various flags example (-S 123.134.543.143)

Comment: I figure out it out, if you create an shell script in the MacOS directory, to execute the actual executable with the correct parameters.